# Canexel warping - How to evaluate the risk, cost of maintenance and cost of replacement?

Tags: sealing, siding, canada

Here's the situation, we are interested into buying this home for our new family but there seems to be an issue with the siding. It's hard for me to evaluate the risk of it. I mean, should I negotiate down the price with the sellers? Does this hide something I'd better assert before buying? Is this normal?:

[image: warping]
[image: warping]
[image: caulk]
[image: caulk]

In other words, what would be your course of action base on those photos? The house has been built in 2003. The only thing i'm sure of is that I'll need to redo the sealing (this is fine by me).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think Canexel is something that's only available in Canada, so I cannot speak to the siding itself. Also (being from the states) I don't know much about the process of purchasing a home up there either. But here's what I would do if I were buying this home. It looks to me like the siding was laid over furring strips, and the installer probably cheaped out and didn't lay the proper number of strips down to prevent overlap or warping. Laying furring strips is a common practice here in the US under siding (typically vinyl which has a lot more flex - less so over hardie or wood because those are easier to offset for the most part). Since this is a purchase I would have the current homeowner repair before signing. It's common in the US to have repairs done as part of negotiating the contract. Again, I don't know what Canexel is so that material may factor into it as well. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You do have good reason to be concerned. But what I see is not warping. The siding where you see gaps at the bottom edge are where the siding is no longer held in place at the bottom. The siding is to be nailed only at the top so the next course above covers the nails that hold it in place. The bottom is held in place by locking into the top of the lower piece. It can be surfaced nailed and needs to be under windows where windows need a rip cut to go under them properly. It looks like the siding has not been locked in well enough in many of the places you have marked with arrows. Back at the surface nailing, The places that are not in plane with the other siding courses can be nailed through the lower edge to bring it back in place, but it MUST be nailed into the studs. I would rather see it done right the first time by having the bottoms properly engaged with the top of the lower course, but that would require a LOT of siding being removed. But since face nailing is acceptable by the maker, it is workable, but criteria must be met. I looked up the [install guide](https://lpcorp.com/resources/product-literature/installation-instructions/lp-canexel-ced-r-vue-installation-instructions-english) for the product, to learn about what I am passing onto you.

The gaps you pointed out are needed as part of the install, but need to be caulked. Since Canexel is a prefinished siding, Canexel has color matched caulk and touch up paint for their products.

All this should be done by a trusted pro and get estimates, if you choose to.  Deduct that cost from the selling price. Or have it done ahead of time as part of the purchase agreement...And get a guarantee from the company that fixes it. If it is not done right, you will still be the one living with it.